# How to apply style through @input property, I want to increase width of mat-autocomplete in angular

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

One of friend rightly pointed out to use property @input as shown in [enter link description here](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/api#MatAutocomple). I want to apply new style and change the width of `mat-autocomplete`.So drop down width is still big.

I am new Angular, I don't know how to use this property, but here is what I tried this is not working.

**compoenent.ts**

```
 @Input() panelWidth: string | number;// I tried initializing this here for ex:50px, gives error
```

tried applying property as attribute to mat-autocomplete as shown below

```html
 <mat-autocomplete panelWidth ="170px" #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith] = "displayFn">
```

Here is the whole template.html code snippet which does autocomplete

```html
  <mat-form-field >
        <input matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto"  [formControl]="customerFilterControl">
           <mat-autocomplete panelWidth ="170px" #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith] = "displayFn">
             <mat-option  *ngFor="let option of (filteredOptions | async)" [value] ="option">
               {{option.name}} {{option.type}}
             </mat-option>
           </mat-autocomplete>
      </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: I have edited question I guess, I must apply property panelWidth ="170px" to mat-autocomplete and not to mat-option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `@Input() panelWidth` in component.ts, this is the definition in documentation. As end user, you should use as as follows,

1. Hard coded value

```html
<mat-autocomplete panelWidth ="170px" ...
```

2. Using variable

```
// define variable in class
widthOfPanel = '170px';
```

use it in HTML with binding,

```html
<mat-autocomplete [panelWidth]="widthOfPanel" ...
```

Comment: Inside component class export class componentClass {    widthOfPanel = '170px'; ...}  then inside template.html <mat-autocomplete [panelWidth] = widthOfPanel .... Bu this hasn't made any change to the mat-autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your styles

```
/deep/ .mat-autocomplete-panel {
    min-width: 133px;
    max-width: 340px;//your desire width
    width: 100%;
}
```

Use `/deep/` when you style in inner `component css` else don't use it if you style in globally in `stlye.scss`

Comment: Hi Awais, I tried your solution /deep/ shows me error in visual code , when I hover on /deep/ it says   'at-rule or selector expected'

Comment: yeah it show but the code gonna work. and one more thing you style that in global styles or component styles

Comment: Hi I styled this in component level not globally

Comment: And for  mat-autocomplete directive adding panelWidth  attribute it indeed applied the style. for ex:  <mat-autocomplete panelWidth ="450px" ...>

Comment: Then you need that `/deep/` selector, for ref visit this https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-host-context/